# How can I plot category data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pivot

I'm trying to plot some category data in R, I've managed to do it before but I just can't seem to get this one! My data looks like this (below). I am trying to plot bar charts for each of the categories (e.g. 0.25, 0.5 etc) with their respective values and facet grid by antimicrobial.

I have converted the data using pivot_longer and specificed the column headings as variables. I have run subsequent ggplot code but it isn't working.

```
graph_01 <- ggplot(data = graphlong,
        aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable)) +
        geom_col() + 
        facet_grid(rows = vars(Antimicrobial))
```

Is there any way to fix this problem? Any help would be much appreciated! :) :)

```
        Antimicrobial  0.25 0.5 1   2   4   8   16
    1   Amox/Clav      95   393 223 3   0   1   0
    2   Ampicillin     48   100 528 35  3   1   0
    3   Cefquinome     0    0   24  28  245 418 0
    4   Doxycycline    554  2   1   5   35  118 0
    5   Enrofloxacin   21   125 355 52  162 0   0
    6   Erythromycin   106  110 236 176 87  0   0
    7   Gentamicin     0    1   13  90  132 479 0
    8   Marbofloxacin  0    25  71  406 213 0   0
    9   Penicillin G   10   6   27  376 259 37  0
```

Comment: Hey Danny, please don’t upload data as images, it’s not very helpful. Could you edit your question to include data as reproducible code? Good luck!

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(graphlong)` (or `graphwide`). Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(graphlong, 20))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Antimicrobial) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(.~Antimicrobial)
```

[image]

---

**Data in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(Antimicrobial = c("Amox/Clav", "Ampicillin", "Cefquinome", 
"Doxycycline", "Enrofloxacin", "Erythromycin", "Gentamicin", 
"Marbofloxacin", "Penicillin G"), `0.25` = c(95L, 48L, 0L, 554L, 
21L, 106L, 0L, 0L, 10L), `0.5` = c(393L, 100L, 0L, 2L, 125L, 
110L, 1L, 25L, 6L), `1` = c(223L, 528L, 24L, 1L, 355L, 236L, 
13L, 71L, 27L), `2` = c(3L, 35L, 28L, 5L, 52L, 176L, 90L, 406L, 
376L), `4` = c(0L, 3L, 245L, 35L, 162L, 87L, 132L, 213L, 259L
), `8` = c(1L, 1L, 418L, 118L, 0L, 0L, 479L, 0L, 37L), `16` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing the dataset, Allan. I have some suggestions for the plot. Please review my code and correct it if there are any errors. Thanks in advance!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
```

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Antimicrobial) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = Antimicrobial)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rainbow(length(unique(df$Antimicrobial)))) +
  facet_wrap(~ Antimicrobial) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Antimicrobial")) +
  theme_pubr() +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "right",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) + 
  ggtitle("Graphic Comparison of Antimicrobial Activities")
```

[graphics plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDuDN.png)

Comment: This works brilliantly as well. Many thanks!